# Why docker not running flask app on 0.0.0.0?

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize my flask app. I see that docker will host on 0.0.0.0. But I am not getting it. My dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/bash
FROM python:3.8
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
#ENTRYPOINT [ "./main_class.py" ]
#CMD [ "flask", "run", "-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "5000" ]
CMD [ "python", "main_class.py", "flask", "run", "-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "5000" ]
```

When I build it , it build successfully. When I run it `docker run -p 5000:5000 iris`, it ran successfully. It says `Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`.
Moreover when I see `172.17.0.2:5000` in browser, it does not work. But if I use `127.0.0.1:5000` it works. How can I bring `0.0.0.0:5000` ? In `main_class.py` I am using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

When I type `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
90a8a1ee3625   iris      "python main_class.p…"   23 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   thirsty_lalande
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing in dockerfile ?

Moreover when I use `ENTRYPOINT`, it shows me an error `standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`, thats why I am not using `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 doesn't mean that the address of the service will be 0.0.0.0. It means that the service will accept connections from all IP addresses. From your description it seems that everything works as it should.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means to bind this port on all network interfaces, including the one that handles public connections.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought 0.0.0.0 is a real IP address. But can you explain that when I typed 172.17.0.2:5000 in browser , it doesn't work even though it says running on 172.17.0.2:5000. But if I go to localhost:5000 its running

Answer (score 3):

The `flask run -h 0.0.0.0` will tell your flask process to bind to any local IP address, as mentioned in the comments. This will also allow flask to respond to your Docker port-forwarding (5000->5000), i.e. to answer incoming traffic from the Docker bridge.

On the Docker level your effective port-forwarding is `0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp` as shown by docker ps, so on your host system port 5000 on any local IP address will be forwarded to your container's flask process.

Please mind that `0.0.0.0` isn't a real IP address, but a placeholder to bind to any local IP address.

You can access your flask application on any IP that routes to your host system, port 5000.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought 0.0.0.0 is a real IP address. But can you explain that when I typed 172.17.0.2:5000 in browser , it doesn't work even though it says running on 172.17.0.2:5000. But if I go to localhost:5000 its running